# The role/meaning of なる in 邪魔をするOrganisationなる”羽虫”

Tags: translation

Big boss leader with his cronies is looking for something and says:

> 先程の赤いおさげが渡してきたデータによるとあの海岸沿いの何処からしい
>
> **邪魔をするOrganisationなる**”羽虫”もいるようだがすべて轢き潰して虱潰しにすれば見つかるであろう

Now IMO this basically boils down to:

> according to the data we got from the pig tailed one, it (what they are searching for) is somewhere along this coast.
>
> Then there is also those gnats from the meddlesome Organisation, but if we smush them one by one, we will be discovered.

The weird bit is the 邪魔をするOrganisationなる”羽虫” specifically "Organisationなる". Why would you mate a noun and なる without the particle. And I don't really see に fitting in there. Unless she is trying to say something like "Insects who'll turn out to be the troublesome organization" or something.

So what's up with that なる?

Also I'm not 100% on who 見つかる refers to (the thing they are looking or them) buuut I can save that for later.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13697/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53077/9831 /

Comment: Could you add this as an answer so I can mark it as such.
Given the links you provided, it seems なる is just the oldey times way to connect nouns to descriptors. So Organisationの”羽虫” would kinda have the similar meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 邪魔をするOrganisationなる"羽虫"
>   a "gnat" called *Organisation* that disturbs us

This なる is the attributive form of the archaic copula なり. In modern Japanese, `AなるB` is a stiff and literary way of saying "B in A", "B that is A", "B known as A" or "B called A", etc.

From 明鏡国語辞典:

> #### なり
>
> ② 《主に連体形「なる」の形で》
>   ㋐ 《場所を表す語に付いて》そこに存在する意を表す。…にある。「自らの内なる思い」「駿河なる富士の高嶺」
>   ㋑ 《名詞に付いて》その名を持つ意を表す。…という。「ロートリンゲンなる王国」「前衛芸術なるもの」

Answer (score 0):

That なる is a auxiliary verb of heresay, in short, the same as という, and the subject for 見つかる is the object the speaker is searching for.

I'm not really sure how to interpret "邪魔をするOrganisation", but it seems to me comparing a certain organization called "Organisation" that disturbs the speaker's group to gnats.

Comment: I haven't heard of a hearsay なる, but I *have* heard of a なる that is equivalent to attributive である.

Comment: @Chocholate is the right one here. The person speaking this tends to use archaic forms. So using  archaic forms of な which is なる in it's function to tie the noun and it's descriptor fits here. 
Gnats of that interfering organization.

Comment: You can look up it by googling "なり 助動詞" or so.

Comment: `That なる is a auxiliary verb of hearsay` -- 「伝聞のなり」でしょうか。　「なり」「助動詞」でググっていくつかのページを見たんですが（辞書  https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A など)、「推定・伝聞」の「なり」は、「活用語の終止形」「ラ変型の活用語の連体形」に付くと書いてあって、体言に接続すると書いてないですが、（体言につく「なり」は断定の「なり」だと書いてあって）、「邪魔をするOrganization」は、体言ですよね。。。？

Comment: 偽古体では接続周りの文法は無視されがちなので、意味論を優先してそのように考えました。断定のなり、つまりコピュラのほうからは、属性を限定する意味か、存在する場所を表す意味（吉野なる寺＝吉野にある寺）しか生まれないはずなので。もっとも、接続を優先して伝聞のなりの意味が混入したとも考えられるとは思います。

Comment: 「Organisationである羽虫」として意味が通るかを考えればいいと思います。

Comment: 明鏡にも[デジタル大辞泉にも](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/165328/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A/)この用法は断定のナリの用法として載っています。デジタル大辞泉には「漢文訓読からの用法」という注釈があるので少し特殊な成立過程なのかもしれませんが。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。